# Make Hatch object in AutoCAD by the use of COM

Tags: python, com, autocad, comtypes

I`m working with AutoCAD drawing using Python language and comtypes library. This is fragment of my code:

```
from comtypes.client import *
from comtypes.automation import *

def connect_acad(self):
    self.acad = GetActiveObject("AutoCAD.Application")
    self.dwg = self.acad.ActiveDocument
    self.mspace = self.dwg.ModelSpace

def mark_point(self, xy, num, lay):

    def point(*args):
        lst = [0.]*3
        if len(args) < 3:
            lst[0:2] = [float(x) for x in args[0:2]]
        else:
            lst = [float(x) for x in args[0:3]]
        return VARIANT(array("d",lst))

    def variant(data):
        return VARIANT(VT_VARIANT, data)

    def vararr(*data):
        if (  len(data) == 1 and 
              isinstance(data, collections.Iterable) ):
            data = data[0]
        return map(variant, data)

    p1 = point(xy[0], xy[1])
    ent = self.mspace.AddCircle(p1, 0.3)
    htch = self.mspace.AddHatch(0, 'SOLID', False)
    htch.AppendOuterLoop(vararr([ent,]))
    htch.Evaluate()
```

If anyone interested, full code here: https://github.com/nsedenkov/py_acadcoord/blob/master/acadcoord.py

And anything works correctly, but command htch.AppendOuterLoop raises exception "ComTypeError". Probably, anyone knows the right way to make variant array from AutoCAD graphical entitys for method AppendOuterLoop? Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

The expected types are:

> Type: Variant (array of Arc, Circle, Ellipse, Line, Polyline, Region, Spline objects)

And I would also recommend double check the condition:

> An array of objects forming a **closed boundary**. The array can consist of one or more objects. If more than one object is used, their endpoints must coincide for the loop to be created properly.

See complete documentation at http://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-mechanical/getting-started/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-ActiveX/files/GUID-4CA06494-CDFF-46FA-9E1D-A0E8220F69F4-htm.html

Comment: Thank you, Augusto! Of cource, I already read this article in Autodesk knowledge base. I also seen this and many another VBA and LISP examples. But what about Python? Native Python supports only numeric array types, but for AppendOuterLoop I need variant array of AutoCAD graphic entitys (Arc, Line, Circle and others) - in my script only 1 circle ((

Comment: I'm not expert on Python... but a few articles mentioning win32com.client.VARIANT, have you tried it? Sorry not being or more help.